# Generic interface inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have created an interface in Java with the following method:

```
interface ReaderInterface{
      public <k,v> Map<k,v> fetch(k id);
      public <k,v> Map<k,v> fetchAll(); 
}
```

Then I have created a class which is implementing that interface:

```
class JSONreaderImpl implements ReaderInterface{
    public Map<String, String> fetchAll(){ 
        // This compiler is allowing to be override from interface \
    }

    public Map<String, String> fetch(String id){ 
        // This is not being considered as an override method, compiler throwing an error to implement the fetch method 
    }

}
```

My question here is why fetchAll method is being considered as an override method on creating it on specific class and why not fetch method.

Could you please help me understand this?

Comment: Sorry, this is not valid Java, I downvoted and voted to close. Your snippets should compile. `Interface`, `Class`, `<k,v> Map<k,v>` don't work

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It simple mistyping, I don't understand why you reverted my edit.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko also `<k,v> Map<k,v>` will work fine. It is little unorthodox to use small letters, but code is valid.

Comment: Did you mean `interface ReaderInterface<k,v> { Map<k,v> fetch(k id); etc }` instead? Using signature `<k,v> Map<k,v> fetch(k id)` doesn't make much sense to me here.

Comment: @talex I agree with the last point - it's a design (not syntactical) issue.  However, you have corrected **five** typos which is a lot and indicates OP didn't even try to compile it. To me, this carelessness is a little sign of disrespect towards the community.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes, but those mistakes are obvious. I don't understand why we have to wait until author will fix them himself.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I understand this is bad design but I just needed to understand the behaviour and I have compiled the code myself and it is giving error. Please be polite in saying anyone anything

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to fetch entities of the same kind with these two methods, aren't you?
The design is incorrect in this case: you should parametrize the whole interface, not each method separately:

```java
interface ReaderInterface<k, v> {
    public Map<k, v> fetch(k id);
    public Map<k, v> fetchAll();
}

class JSONreaderImpl implements ReaderInterface<String, String> {
    public Map<String, String> fetchAll() {  return null; }

    public Map<String, String> fetch(String id) {  return null;  }
}
```

Otherwise (parametrizing each method separately, you are intended to allow implementations like

```java
    public Map<String, Boolean> fetchAll() {  return null; }
    public Map<Integer, List<Double>> fetch(Integer id) {  return null;  }
```

Comment: That is not what question is about. It is generic methods in question, not generic class.

Comment: @talex you are right. Explained in a separate answer. Thank you for returning the conversation back to the point.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why `fetch` doesn't work you can look into next example.

```
ReaderInterface foo = new JSONreaderImpl();
foo.<Integer, Integer>fetch(Integer.valueOf(1));
```

It is call `fetch` with `<Integer, Integer>` generic parameters, but implementation expect them to be `<String, String>`. To prevent this compiler raise an error.

I don't understand why `fetchAll` works. Probably some erasure magic, and it is actually raise warning about "unchecked overriding".

Comment: Thats why I had this question, why the behaviour is like this?

Comment: Because otherwise compiler cant ensure type safety.

Answer (score 1):

@talex is right and the original question definitely worth answering despite the provocative design.

[Type erasure for generic methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html)
explains that the unbounded type parameter is compiled to `Object`.
So, declaring this interface

```java
interface Q {
  public <K, V> Map<K, V> fetch(K id);
}
```

you do have the following interface to be extended at runtime

```java
interface Q {
  public Map<Object, Object> fetch(Object id);
}
```

The compiler pays special attention to the method arguments as they participate in the *proper signature to call* detection, it does not allow you to make the declared argument type more specific and stay in the same signature at the same time. 
The return type does not bother the compiler us much.

So you can have the following implementation been detected as the same signature

```java
abstract class QA implements Q {
  public abstract Map<Integer, String> fetch(Object id);
}
```

but cannot have this in this role:

```java
abstract class QA implements Q {
  public abstract Map<Integer, String> fetch(Integer id);
}
```

If you actually want some sort of specific for the method argument, *bound* your type parameter somehow - thus it can be compiled with wider information.

```java
interface O {
    <K extends List, V> V process(K id);
}

abstract  class OA implements O {
    public abstract String process(List id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the questions is not completely clear , but if this is what you are trying to achieve

```
interface Reader<T>.
{ 
  Map fetchAll(); 
  Map fetch(T id); 
}
```

Impl

```
public class JSONReader implements Reader<String> 
{ 
  @Override
  Map<String, String> fetch(String id)
  { 
   // code
  }
  @Override 
  Map<String, String> fetchAll()
  { 
    //code
  }  
}
```

Comment: if something in the question is not completely clear to you, please don't answer. It's really better to clarify it in the comments